# Fractional Factorial Design with Highest Resolution

Tags: self-study, anova, experiment-design, degrees-of-freedom, fractional-factorial

In  the book `Design and Analysis of Experiments` by Douglas C. Montgomery , it is written that

> We usually like to employ fractional designs that have the highest possible resolution consistent with the degree of fractionation required.

But the situation described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114917/fractional-factorial-design) is a $2^{5-2}$ design of resolution $3$.

- Can't i also do $2^{5-1}$ design of resolution $5$ ?

If so , then my condition of minimum number of runs doesn't satisfy.

And if i don't do $2^{5-1}$ design of resolution $5$, then the condition of `to employ fractional designs that have the highest possible resolution consistent with the degree of fractionation required` doesn't satisfy.

Is that really  horns of a dilemma or i am doing wrong to understand.

Comment: I am interested in your question, but don't understand it yet.  It seems to me that a $2^{5-1}_V$ design has 16 runs, so if your "degree of fractionation required" means you need 8 runs then you will not be able to use that better design.